# Is this how to check if an object has no related objects in templates?

Tags: python, django

This is what I currently has to check if the author has some photos in the related photo model:

```
{% if author.photo_set.count > 0 %}
<h2>...</h2>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div class="author_pic">
    {% for photo in author.photo_set.all %}
        <img src="..." />
    {% endfor %}
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
{% endif %}
```

Is this the right way or I can avoid having two queries somehow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `with` tag to avoid multiple queries.

```html
{% with author.photo_set.all as photos %}
    {% if photos %}
    <h2>...</h2>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div class="author_pic">
        {% for photo in photos %}
            <img src="..." />
        {% endfor %}
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

There is also the `empty` tag that you can use within a for loop, but that probably doesn't apply to your example.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#for-empty

```
<ul>
{% for athlete in athlete_list %}
    <li>{{ athlete.name }}</li>
{% empty %}
    <li>Sorry, no athlete in this list!</li>
{% endfor %}
<ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

AS @pyrospade suggsted, you can look if the photos object exists. Or you could also check the length (check the [length](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/templates/builtins/#length) template tag) of the list of photo_set as follows:

```
{% if author.photo_set.all|length > 0 %}
    <h2>...</h2>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div class="author_pic">
        {% for photo in author.photo_set.all %}
            <img src="..." />
        {% endfor %}
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
{% endif %}
```